# If Average calculated column

Tags: 2007, calculated-column

I am using SharePoint 2007 and trying to automate a couple of columns using calculated value. I have three columns that you enter a number and in the 4th column it totals the average (this works fine). However, I am trying to add a 5th column that a assigns a ranking based on the average score and can't get it to work. If I put the formula in Excel it works perfectly, but not in SharePoint. What am I doing wrong?

Option A

```
=IF(
    AVERAGE([Call 1 Score %],[Call 2 Score %],[Call 3 Score %])<85
    ,"DO"
    ,IF(
        AVERAGE([Call 1 Score %],[Call 2 Score %],[Call 3 Score %])<93
        ,"SP"
        ,"RM"
       )
   )
```

Option B

```
=IF(
    Combined Score Avg<85
    ,"DO"
    ,IF(
        Combui<93
        ,"SP"
        ,IF(
            B2>92.9
            ,"RM"

           )
       )
   )
```

Example

The bolded example column is where the trouble is.

```
Call1     Call2     Call3       Avg      Rating
85        92          78        85        **SP**
```

Comment: In Excel you can access other rows and apply formula on them, in SharePoint Calculated Columns you can't access other rows / list items and apply formula on them. You can only use fields of same row / list item.

Comment: Correct these are the same row. Essentially, column 1, 2, and 3 of the row need to be averaged in column 4 (already works), then column 5 needs to take the data and assign a rating.

Comment: `column 5 needs to take the data` which data? if that means data from other list items, it's not possible via calculated column only

Comment: same list, same row

Comment: You mean you have a third Formula  Rating? What happens if you name it anything but Rating? In SP2010 that became a special SP column, maybe it was already there in 2007

Comment: I technically have it as Monitor Rating, but was abbreviating for the example. I am working off sharepoint 2007 so I know there's some limitations. but basically the 4th and 5th columns are returning different information based on the 1st three columns

Comment: `=IF(CustomAvg<=20,"SP",IF(CustomAvg<=35,"AP",IF(CustomAvg<=50,"HC","NONE")))` this formula works for me in SP 2013, where CustomAvg is the Calculated column with formula to calculate Average

Comment: Thanks Arsalan, unfortunately 2007 does not have the CustomAvg function. I tried to mirror your formula replacing customavg with my calculated value column but it didn't work. Do you know how this might work for SharePoint 2007

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out what the issue was. From a technical standpoint the formulas are correct, but because the columns that the formula was pulling from were % columns, the formula needed to include %. I ended up using the simplified version. It is below for reference. Thanks everyone for the assistance.

=IF([Combined Score} Avg<85%,"DO",IF([Combined Score Avg]<93%,"SP","RM"))